# Cant get the value of <li data-*> element. Tried Javascript as well as Jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

The following is my dropdown list.

```
<ul id="navBar" data-value="">
        <li data-city-value="blore"><a href="#">Bangalore</a>
            <ul>
                <li data-city-value="delhi"><a href="#">Delhi</a></li>
                <li data-city-value="che"><a href="#">Chennai</a></li>
                <li data-city-value="jaipur"><a href="#">Jaipur</a></li>
                <li data-city-value="hyd"><a href="#">Hyderabad</a></li>
                <li data-city-value="mum"><a href="#">Mumbai</a></li>
                <li data-city-value="pune"><a href="#">Pune</a></li>
            </ul>
        </li>
    </ul>
```

And the following are my methods I tried to access the data-city-value attribute.

Method 1)

```
var cityName = document.getElementById('navBar');
var city = cityName.getAttribute('data-city-value');
alert(city);
```

It alerts "null"

Method 2)

```
var cityName = document.getElementById('navBar');
var city = cityName.dataset.cityValue;
alert(city);
```

It alerts "undefined".

Method 3)

```
$('#navBar li').click(function() {
    $(this).parent().data('value', $(this).data('cityValue')); 
  });
  alert($('#city').data('value'));
```

It alerts "undefined".

I checked the syntax to get data value [here](http://html5doctor.com/html5-custom-data-attributes/)

It would be of great help if you can help me find where I am doing mistake.

Thanks. :)

Comment: That attribute doesn't exist on the element you're fetching by ID, so naturally it won't give you the value you want.

Comment: Are you trying to get the value when the user clicks the anchor or all the values?

Comment: In methods 1 and 2 you are trying to get the `data-city-value` of the ul element, not the li, and your `<ul id="navBar">` does not have `data-city-value`. You need to select a particular li element. In Method 3 - the $(..).data(..) method works with the name of the attribute after `data-`, i.e. you need to use `$(this).data('city-value')` (without converting it to camelCase).

Answer (score 2):

IN your first two methods you target the top `ul` with id `navBar`. In the third method you do `$(this).parent()` which again takes you to the `ul` element.

That element does not have the `data-city-value` attribute.

The jquery method should be

```
$('#navBar').on('click','li', function(e) {
    var city = $(this).data('city-value');
    alert(city);
    return false;
});
```

Demo at http://jsfiddle.net/gaby/Mb7KS/

Comment: $(this).parent() is used in the set, i.e. trying to set the data-value of the UL element to the value of data-city-value of the li element. But since this is a nested list, I would just modify your code, just below the alert (or in place of) - `$(e.delegateTarget).data('value', city);`

Answer (score 0):

This is how you can iterate through your data-city-value attributes:

```
 $('li[data-city-value]').each(function(index,element){
        alert($(element).data('city-value'));
 });
```

You can also check my [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/bmfHe/) example.

For click events:

```
$(document).ready(function()
{

    $('li').click(function() {
        alert($(this).data('city-value'));
        return false;
    });
});
```

You should return false because the top li element has inner elements and it was triggering inner li element click event.

My second [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/bmfHe/1/) demo.

Answer (score 0):

As pointed out by Gaby, you need to reach the

element firts. Try this:

```
$('#navBar:first-child')
```